# Programmatically launch multiple slide shows using python-uno

Tags: openoffice.org

I have been using the Python-uno interface to launch OpenOffice and run PowerPoint slide shows on a Linux-based noticeboard system. Now the customer wants to make a split-screen and show four different slide shows on the screen at the same time.

But whenever I start a slide show in a second instance of OpenOffice, the first slide show will freeze.

Has anyone out there encountered this problem before?  Anyone solved it?

I am running OpenOffice 2.4 on Debian Linux. I run two completely separate instances of OpenOffice in separate processes but they seem to affect each other anyway.

Comment: Have you tried openoffice 3.0?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a dead post, but I think it would be useful for anybody else who has this problem.

Try going to [this forum](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=1051). You could try to use an OpenOffice macro and accessing it with a python function. Here is the macro code:

```
Sub hello 

    dim xPresentation as object 
    set xPresentation = thiscomponent.getpresentation 
    xPresentation.setPropertyValue("IsEndless", true)  'loops around 
    xPresentation.start() 

End Sub
```

For the python part, I think you would need to invoke /usr/bin/soffice (possibly /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice) with the URL "macro:///MyLibrary/MyModule/MyFunction(/home/foo/bar/MyImpressDoc.sxi"